# Can I recover my Safari history after running CCleaner?

Tags: safari

I did a default delete of Safari data using CCleaner. Is there any way I can recover my browser history and more importantly the exact timing I viewed a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari History data lives in ~/Library/Safari/ so you could restore that from Time Machine - though it might be better to just restore the entire Safari folder, in case CCleaner did more damage.

If you sync Safari over iCloud, switch of any other devices as soon as possible to prevent them also syncing the lost data, then having to sync it all back again afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for that .. though is your viewing timed though too ?..or is it just dated ?.

Comment: @Briser48 TimeMachine can only restore data which was there originally, so you will get the same level of granularity as you had *before* deleting the data.

Comment: Noel, im an a novice so forgive me .Am I able to see the time though on visited websites

Comment: History only shows 'date last visited' in Safari. To perhaps get finer granularity you'd need to be able to open the .db file, which is completely beyond my skill-set.